# corda 4: Nodes communicating previously with each other does not identify each other after restart even when flows are not modified

Tags: corda

We are building a POC using Corda 4 and Springboot web server.

The POC is running in **DEV MODE** in our local network.

The CorDapp developed for POC has four nodes -

1. Provider Node
2. Consumer 1 Node
3. Consumer 2 Node
4. Notary Node

Every deal that takes place between the three nodes have three flows. Following are the three flows and the states:

1. Flow 1: Provider Node --> Consumer 1 Node
2. Flow 2: Consumer 1 Node --> Consumer 2 Node and Provider Node
3. Flow 3: Consumer 2 Node -- > Consumer 1 Node and Provider Node

I executed first two flows on July 7, 2021 -

1. Flow 1 from "Provider Node" to "Consumer 1 Node" and
2. Flow 2 from "Consumer 1 Node" to  "Consumer 2 Node" and Provider Node".

**Both flows were successful**

I stopped the nodes after the Flow 2.

Next day, on July 8, 2021, I restarted the nodes.

I initiated Flow 3 from "Consumer 2 Node" to "Consumer 1 Node and Provider Node".

**It failed**

> *Error thrown: "The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must pass in exactly the sessions required to sign the transaction."*

I then initiated Flow 1 for "Provider Node" to "Consumer 1 Node"

**It failed too**

> *Error thrown: "Don't know about OU=Bank, O=MyBank, L=Houston, C=U"*

**Question:**

1. What could be the reason for the above?
2. Should I redeploy the nodes every time after the nodes are stopped?

Comment: You don't have to redeploy the nodes every time you stop and start. Have all the flows ran successfully even once?

Comment: Yes. They were running successfully.

Comment: If they were running successfully before, they should run in the same way after restart also. A simple restart will not cause this issue. Did you upgrade the flow jar after stopping the nodes?

Comment: I am starting four nodes independently using following commad - "java -Dcapsule.jvm.args="-Xmx2048m" -jar corda.jar"

Does this command upgrades the flow jar?

Comment: I didn't upgraded the flow jar. I just restarted the nodes and tried the flows.

Comment: No that will not upgrade the flow. I have pinged you on slack, we can have a detailed discussion there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [corda 4.0 - deploying an updated cordpp having modified flows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68287751/corda-4-0-deploying-an-updated-cordpp-having-modified-flows)

Comment: No. Both questions are different. In this question  flows are not modified.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a PostgreqSQL database, when you do a clean deploy, the clean command doesn't clean the postgres database, unlike h2 database.

Ideally, in production system, it is expected that you will deploy your cordapp once, later of course you can upgrade your contract, states and flows when required but you will never clean off completely the database completely.

So right now what is happening is when you deploy your cordapp for the first time, certificates are generated by the bootstrapper tool(you can find these in build/nodes/PartyA/certificates folder), they are also saved in the DB. NodeInfos are also saved here build/nodes/PartyA/

When you do a clean build, the build folder is cleaned but the database is not cleaned and gets corrupted with the new entries which also has the new entries, and the node is confused with which entry to use.

So the solution is to drop and recreate the schemas in the database as well when you do a clean deploy at the node.

Answer (score 0):

1. your flow seems to have a mismatch between the required signers for the transactions and the required participants in the state when trying to finalize the transaction.
2. not sure what you mean by 'redeploy' the nodes but you don't have to restart them every time. You shouldn't have to redeploy or restart them at all ideally.

thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found that by **regenerating the node infos** again before restarting the nodes, I was able to execute all the flows even after stopping and starting the nodes.

Commands used for regenerating the node infos :

```
java -jar corda.jar clear-network-cache
java -jar corda.jar generate-node-info
```

These commands were run from the "/build/nodes/" folder of each node.